# Is there a way to use java to write a program that will display an image at the top layer

Tags: java, image

Essentially I want to do something like what MSI afterburner does with its FPS and temp monitor... I want to display text (or an image would be better) at the top level of my screen, regardless of what other programs or windows are open.

For example, if I am running a game in full-screen, and I want the time to be displayed in the top right corner of my screen, can I use some Class(es) to get that capability? If so, where should I look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One piece of the puzzle -- placing a Window on top (without SWT) is described here: ["Always on Top" Windows with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297938/always-on-top-windows-with-java)

Answer (score 4):

From Java 6 Update 10 and onward, [Swing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) now has support for transparent windows and non-rectangular windows.

The Sun Developer Network has an article called [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/GUI/translucent_shaped_windows/) which includes sample code and illustrative pictures to show what is now possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and tell the window you want it to stay on top, and you can [disable the window borders and such](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505599/custom-widget-shapes-in-swt) if you want a custom window. The only problem is that 'the always on top' property isn't easily changable at runtime without some hacking with the API of whatever OS you're using.

Edit: the linked question also has SWT.ON_TOP code, and should hide the background. Happy days.